# Maze Recursion and shortest path

Tags: c#, recursion, xna, maze

I know this isn't perfect, and I know that it isn't near done. The board is a 19 by 19 array, where 1's represent empty squares. Right now, it will go straight down, then go west. If there is a wall to the left of it, then it will have a stack overflow. The reason why is when it trys to 'climb' up the wall, it ends up going back down over and over and crashes. Even if I fix this, though, it wont find the shortest path. The solutions I've found draw paths, not count how many squares it is away.

```
private static int turnsforshortestmove(Vector2 location, int[,] board, int endrow)
{
    if (location.Y == endrow)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (board[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y - 1] == 1)
    {
        return 1 + turnsforshortestmove(new Vector2(location.X, location.Y - 2), board, endrow);
    }
    else if (board[(int)location.X - 1, (int)location.Y] == 1)
    {
        return 1 + turnsforshortestmove(new Vector2(location.X - 2, location.Y), board, endrow);
    }
    else if (board[(int)location.X, (int)location.Y + 1] == 1)
    {
        return 1 + turnsforshortestmove(new Vector2(location.X, location.Y + 2), board, endrow);
    }
    else if (board[(int)location.X + 1, (int)location.Y ] == 1)
    {
        return 1 + turnsforshortestmove(new Vector2(location.X + 2, location.Y), board, endrow);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look for Djikstra algorithm. Your algorithm is just an incorrect implementation of search in depth (why do you assume that going to the first available direction will give you the result that you want?)

Comment: why do you assume that I didn't know this won't give me the right direction.

Comment: You neglected to ask a question; you just told a story about some broken code. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a path-finding problem.  As SJuan76 has already suggested, [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is the best starting point for this sort of problem.

Given a grid-style map of open/blocked squares where only orthogonal moves (up, down, left and right) are allowed and each move costs the same amount, finding a path from one grid cell to another involves a fairly simple but time-consuming iteration over possible moves.

The basic principle is to create a list of possible moves and process each one looking for the shortest path.  In each step you check the possible moves from the current position, check if the target location has been moved to previously, and add the ones that haven't been checked already - or that can be moved to more quickly than the previous check - to the list to be processed.  Keep processing the list until you find the location you're aiming for.

***How*** you do this is the fun part.

There are a few things you need to get started on this:

- A method for finding possible moves from an arbitrary point in the grid.
- A way to track locations you've already visited, and what location they were visited from.
- A fast way to figure out the best location to check next.

Given that you're working from a simple square grid, that you're only doing orthogonal moves (up, down, left, right) and that all moves will cost the same, you can gloss over some of the concepts that are not useful in your scenario.  So...

1. Create two collections: one to store the list of locations to `process`, and one to store the list of `visited` locations.
2. Add your starting point to the `process` list.
3. While the `process` list is not empty

   1. Get the next location from the `process` list
   2. If current location is the target, return the list of previous locations that form the path.
   3. Find available moves from that location, excluding any moves in the `visited` list
   4. Push all un-visited possible moves into the `process` list

Eventually, one of two things will happen: either you'll run out of possible moves that haven't already been checked, or you will find your target point.

Here's a structure similar to what I used last time I did path-finding like this:

```
public struct SearchNode
{
    public Vector2 position;
    public SearchNode prior;
    public int TotalCost;
}
```

The `visited` list can be done with a Dictionary:

```
var visited = new Dictionary<Vector2, SearchNode>();
```

The `process` list can be done with a bunch of collection types.  The simplest form would be:

```
var process = new Queue<Vector2>();
```

Hopefully I've given you something to start with.